# Drupal taxonomy terms with views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I need to achieve some basic tasks by using taxonomy terms. I hope Drupal lovers can help me. I have food categories and food products under these categories. I need to show on a page food categories and clicking these categories needs to redirect related products for each category. Firstly i created taxonomy glossary and added food categories as terms. Basically for categories page I created a view and and added filter of taxonomy glossary for food categories. And I am able to show categories properly. Secondly created a content type for food produts which needs to provide users add products by using admin panel. This content type has field to select taxonomy terms. **And I need a page which is able to show food products filtered by taxonomy term as mysite.com/categories/term name?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your taxonomy as per your description is available to add in a field of content type, then which ever content will be tagged with a term will be available on taxonomy term page in teaser by default.

If you need to set some custom path for your taxonomy terms then take help of [pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module and set it. Bulk update it & then visit the terms page as per your given structure..

You can use manage display tab at content type to set the display for teaser.

Comment: I have no problem with taxonomy terms page, but I'd like to show content related each term by using view. (e.g. Food products(content) under the food categories(taxonomy terms). No problem with showing terms.